# Accessing Pandas dataframe values when index values contained in separate numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a numpy `array` of over 2 million `int`s:

```
a = np.array([324, 986, 574 ... 986, 1232, 3943])
```

Each element in `a` corresponds to an index value in a dataframe `df` with shape (1324, 4):

```
index A     B C D
0     'foo' 2 3 2
1     'bar' 2 4 8
...
1323  'foo' 2 5 8
```

I am trying to access the values of `df.A` using a list comprehension:

```
l = [df.A.loc[i] for i in a]
```

but this is taking quite a long time to run.  Is there a faster option; maybe I need to do a [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)?  Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the value in `a` corresponds to the value in the data frame's index, you should be able to just use [`.loc[a]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html); if the values in `a` refers to positions, then you need [`.iloc[a]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html); if you need numpy arrays as result, as commented by @Scott, use `df.A.loc[a].values`:

```
df.A.loc[a]
```

*Example*:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        "A": ["a", "c", "b", "d"]
    })

a = np.array([0,3,2,2,1,1,0])

df.A.loc[a]
#0    a
#3    d
#2    b
#2    b
#1    c
#1    c
#0    a
#Name: A, dtype: object

df.A.loc[a].values
# array(['a', 'd', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done via boolean indexing:

```
a = np.array([324, 986, 574, 986, 1232, 3943])

df
   some_column
0            1
1            2
2            3
3            5
4          324
5          574
6          986
7         3943

df[df['some_column'].isin(a)]
   some_column
4          324
5          574
6          986
7         3943

df[df['some_column'].isin(a)].values
array([[ 324],
       [ 574],
       [ 986],
       [3943]], dtype=int64)
```

Similarly, if the array values correspond with the index:

```
df[df.index.isin(a)]
```

Comment: I need to return an array of the same length as `a` (~2 million) but with the values of `df.A`.  There will be repeat values in the new array (which is the desired outcome).

Comment: Using `df[df.A.isin(a)].values` is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Nah, that would return the values of `df.A` that are in `a`.  I am looking to instead return the corresponding value of `df.A.loc[a[i]]`.